# Convert an Array to unique values only while maintaining the correct sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have the following code:

```
function uniteUnique(arr) {
  //Create a single Array of value  
  arr = arguments[0].concat(arguments[1], arguments[2]);
  //Reduce the Array to unique values only
  arr = arr.reduce((pre, curr) => {
    //Some function to reduce values
  });
  return arr;
}

uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]);
```

The goal is to produce a single Array containing only unique values while maintaining the order.

Currently it returns:

```
[1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1]
```

I'm wanting to reduce this to:

```
[1, 3, 2, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for that:

```js
function uniteUnique(...args) {
    return [...new Set([].concat(...args))];
}
var u = uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]);
console.log(u);
```

It maintains insertion order, and by nature only contains unique values.

In ES5 you could do it by maintaining the used values as properties of a temporary object, while building the result array:

```js
function uniteUnique(/* args */) {
    return [].concat.apply([], arguments).reduce(function (acc, v) {
        if (!acc[0][v]) acc[0][v] = acc[1].push(v); // assigns new length, i.e. > 0
        return acc;
    }, [ Object.create(null), [] ])[1];
}
var u = uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]);
console.log(u);
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `concat` method here. `[...new Set([...args])];`

Comment: @Sushanath, no that would turn the arguments into a nested array, and so the set would become a set of arrays, not of individual values.

Comment: Looks like I did not read the question correctly. Thought the OP's question was related to a single array. But in this case, it's a nested one/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Set object since it already keeps your values unique in one object:

```
const mySet = new Set([1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1]);
// returns:   Set { 1, 3, 4, 5 };

const arrayUniques = [...mySet];

console.log(arrayUniques); 
// returns:  [1, 3, 4, 5];
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I forgot about the power of the Set object.